# "All angles which are integral multiples of $\pi \frac12$ are called quadrantal angles." What does it mean?

Tags: trigonometry

So, I was doing trig functions and came across this notation. I tried my best to understand what did it mean but couldn't. Can you put some light on the answer to this question with help of examples?

Comment: $\pi/2$ is a right angle. I've never heard of "quadrantal angles before" but it appears that they consist of a whole number of right angles, so it's a concept that makes some sort of sense.

Comment: Can you cite an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quadrantal angle is simply any angle which is a multiple of $90^\circ$. In the case of angles measured in radians, these angles are integers multiplied by $\frac\pi2$.

Examples of these angles are:

In degrees, $-90^\circ, 0^\circ, 90^\circ, 180^\circ, 270^\circ,$ etc.

In radians, $-\frac\pi2, 0, \frac\pi2, \frac{2\pi}2, \frac{3\pi}2$, etc.

Comment: Integral multiple means it is multiplied by an integer.

Comment: So, is 7$\pi$/2 a quadrantal angle? Because I multiplied $\pi$/2 by 7?

Comment: @SakshamSharma yes

Comment: And negative too? like -7$\pi$/5?

Comment: All quadrantal angles are either of the form $k\pi$ or $\frac{k\pi}2$ for some $k=\cdots-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, \cdots$. So your example actually does not work, as it is not an integer times $\frac\pi2$.

Comment: They can be negative, but the $5$ in the denominator does not work -- that's a rational multiple of $\pi/2$, not an *integral* multiple. Negative just means your turns in the circle are going in the opposite orientation (so, clockwise).

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Why ? If $\pi$/2 is essentially the first quadrant of a unit circle then why can't I multiply it by -7/5 because -7$\pi$/5 will also make an angle in radians $but$ in the clockwise direction.

Comment: You can multiply it by $-7$, or by $-5$, but not by $-7/5$. That's because $-7$ and $-5$ are integers, but $-7/5$ isn't.

Answer (score 4):

It means that angles of the form $k\cdot \frac\pi2$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, are called 'qaudrantal angles'.

In the usual drawing of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, these are the angles of the $x$ and $y$ axes (with orientation), and divide the plane into four quadrants (hence the name).

Comment: So, is 7$\pi$/2 a quadrantal angle? Because I multiplied $\pi$/2 by 7?

Comment: Under the given definition, yes! Although, in terms of how one usually thinks of angles, $7\pi/2$ corresponds to the same angle as $3\pi/2$ -- it's just we've taken one additional full turn on the circle.

Comment: Notice that the definition just 'makes sense', but it's not, as far as I know, common notation. I myself had never heard of 'quadrantal angles' before this question.

Comment: But it just uses a common concept of what we call a 'multiple'? Right? like 7s multiples are 14,21,28...Likewise we have "integral multiples" whose difference is just that they are multipled by integers that include negative sign too. (like $\pi$/2 multipled by +or-$\pi$, + or - $\pi$/2 and so on. Right?

Comment: No. The integral multiples of $\pi/2$ are $\pi/2$ multiplied by $0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\dots$. You cannot multiply it by fractions like $5/3$ or irrational numbers like $\sqrt2, \pi$.

Comment: Ok. What if we take here rational multiples of $\pi$/2? Will -7$\pi$/5 work then?

Comment: Yes, $-7\pi/5$ is a rational multiple of $\pi/2$. Namely, that's $\pi/2 \cdot (-14/5)$. Observe, though, that it's not a quadrantal angle.

Comment: Sir can you please answer this question of mine? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510243/trigonometric-ratios-for-angles-greater-than-90-degrees-in-unit-circle I shall be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

All angles which are *integer* multiples of $\pi/2$ are called quadrantal angles, *because* these are the angles for the rays of the horizontal and vertical axii, which divide the Cartessian plane into quadrants.

$$\left\{\frac{k\pi}2: k\in\Bbb Z \right\}~=~\left\{\ldots, 0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}2, \ldots \right\}$$

Comment: Can it include a negative angle? like -$\pi$?

Comment: @SakshamSharma Indeed.  All integers; not just the positive.  As indicated by the ellipsis extending in both directions.

Comment: Sir, can you answer this question of mine? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510243/trigonometric-ratios-for-angles-greater-than-90-degrees-in-unit-circle